# Filter Pivot Table with Input Box

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, inputbox

Need some help, just can't see what is wrong here. Trying to Filter a Pivot Table by date entered in Input Box. I keep getting error;

1004 Unable to set the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class.

However, my field is called "Financial Month" so have no idea why it isn't working.

My code is:

```
Sub Select_Pivot()

    Dim DateSelect As String

    DateSelect = InputBox(Prompt:="Search Date", Title:="Enter Date as <Month Year> i.e. May 2017")
    Sheets("CPR").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Financial Month") = DateSelect

End Sub
```

Any ideas? Been trawling the internet and just can't find a solution. Greatly appreciate any advice here please.

Comment: If you go to the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) and type `?Sheets("CPR").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Financial Month").Name` +Enter, what do you get?

Comment: I get "Reference not Valid" but when I look at the Pivot Table fields, it clearly shows as "Financial Month" - thank you for replying so quickly @Excelosaurus

Comment: If your PivotField is a Filter for your whole PivotTable, the property you should be assigning to is `.CurrentPage` as in `(...).CurrentPage = DateSelect`;  the default property for a PivotField is its `Name`. If this doesn't work, please go to the Immediate Window and try `?Sheets("CPR").Name`, then `?Sheets("CPR").PivotTables("PivotTable1").Name`

Comment: Thanks @Excelosaurus - I did try '.CurrentPage' but I get the same 1004 error

Comment: I did a GoTo for both as you listed above and get "Reference not Valid" which again is weird as even the sheet is clearly labelled "CPR"

Comment: So, let me get this straight: from Excel, you press Alt+F11 to get to the VBA editor; you press Ctrl+G to get to the Immediate Window; you type `?Sheets("CPR").Name` and press Enter, and an error message box shows up, saying "Reference is not valid.". Right?

Comment: Sorry @Excelosaurus I was CTRL+G from the worksheet. This is what I get...
?Sheets("CPR").Name
CPR
?Sheets("CPR").PivotTables("PivotTable1").Name
PivotTable1

Comment: If I run '?Sheets("CPR").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Finan‌​cial Month").Name ' I get the 1004 error

Comment: Still from the Immediate Window, type `for each pf in Sheets("CPR").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields:?pf.name:next` and press Enter. Check that "Financial Month" appears. If not, you're not using the right name.

Comment: I get.....[Period].[Financial Month].[Financial Month]

Comment: Change the code in your question: `Sheets("CPR").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Period].[Financial Month].[Financial Month]").Value = DateSelect`

Comment: Just tried it, same 1004 error

Comment: What's the text of the 1004 error?

Comment: 1004 Unable to set the Value property of the PivotField class.

Comment: Where is your PivotField appearing? In Filter, in Row or in Column?

Comment: It's in Filter.

Comment: `Sheets("CPR").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Perio‌​d].[Financial Month].[Financial Month]").CurrentPage = DateSelect`

Comment: When I run it I get "Unable to set the CurrentPage property of the PivotField class. If I remove .currentpage, I then get "Unable to set the _Default property of the PivotField class".

Comment: Really appreciate your time mate, sorry about this

Comment: Do you know how to record a macro? You could record a macro while you change the Filter value, then look at the generated code. Isolate the line with the CurrentPage reference, and try to execute it from the Immediate Window.

Comment: I get this:   
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[Period].[Financial Month].[Financial Month]").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[Period].[Financial Month].[Financial Month]").CurrentPageName = _
        "[Period].[Financial Month].&[2017-05-01T00:00:00]"

Comment: From the IW, is `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Period].[Financial Month].[Financial Month]").CurrentPageName = "[Period].[Financial Month].&[2017-05-01T00:00:00]"` successful?

Comment: Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas and off for the night.

Comment: No problem @Excelosaurus - really appreciate you trying, thanks a million mate

Comment: @JaysonD, did you try adding a `Pivot Filter`, like,      `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Financial Month"). _
        PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:="1/1/2017"`.

Comment: Thanks @Arul - Not sure how I would incorporate that into my code though (sorry I am really new to all this). Also, does it matter that the data is OLAP?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Select_Pivot()

Dim DateSelect As String
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtItm As PivotItem

DateSelect = InputBox(Prompt:="Search Date", Title:="Enter Date as <Month Year> i.e. May 2017")

' set the Pivot-Table object
Set PvtTbl = Sheets("CPR").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

With PvtTbl
    With .PivotFields("Financial Month")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each PvtItm In .PivotItems ' loop through all items in "Financial Month"
            If PvtItm.Name = DateSelect Then
                PvtItm.Visible = True
            Else
                PvtItm.Visible = False
            End If
        Next PvtItm
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks sorry I took long to reply it was night time and had gone to bed. I tried it but it wasn't working because of PivotFields was incorrect, being OLAP it is ("[Perio‌​‌​d].[Financial Month].[Financial Month]"). I changed it and it seemed to work, it hung for a while as the data is BIG but then it finished running and nothing happened apart from the PivotField clearing.

Comment: *bump* sorry I hate to bump but I just can't find a solution to this, anybody else have an idea? Above code from Shai Rado seems to be doing something (clears the filter then just runs for a while then ends, no results, no errors, nothing).